# Android not writing to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to generate String versions of comments by users and add it to Firebase with button clicks. I only write to the database in this class and then I read from the database with a different button that takes me to a different class.

I looked through similar posts and tried those solutions, but none of them worked for me. I changed the rules so that authentication isn't required as well. I've attached my code for it here:

```
 /**
 * create 3 edit texts to be edited by app user
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fill_out_comment);

    addCommentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCommentButton);
    chooseSongEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chosenSong);
    songRatingEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.songRating);
    songCommentEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.songComment);

    chooseSongEdit.setText("");
    songRatingEdit.setText("");
    songCommentEdit.setText("");

}

/**
 * returns song user is commenting on
 *
 * @return string
 */
public String getChosenSong() {
    EditText chooseSongEdit = (EditText)    findViewById(R.id.chosenSong);
    String chosenSong = chooseSongEdit.getText().toString();
    return chosenSong;
}

/**
 * returns user song rating
 *
 * @return double
 */
public double getSongRating() {
    EditText songRatingEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.songRating);
    String songRatingStr = songRatingEdit.getText().toString();
    return Double.parseDouble(songRatingStr);
}

/**
 * returns full user comment
 *
 * @return string
 */
public String getSongComment() {
    EditText songCommentEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.songComment);
    String songCommentStr = songCommentEdit.getText().toString();
    return songCommentStr;
}


/**
 * generates full comment; add comment to database
 * @param view
 * @return string
 */
public void generateComment(View view) {
    //create strings and doubles of user inputs from edit texts
    String chosenSong = getChosenSong();
    Double songRating = getSongRating();
    String songComment = getSongComment();

    //create StringBuilder that wil contain final comment to be put into setText
    StringBuilder tempCommentStr = new StringBuilder();

    //get user ID to display on comment
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = "Null User";
    if (user != null){
         uid = user.getUid();
    }

    tempCommentStr.append("User: " + uid + "\nSong: " + chosenSong + "\nRating: " +
            songRating + "\nComment: " + songComment);

    addCommenttoFirebase = tempCommentStr.toString();

}

public void buttonSaveComment(View view) {
    addCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            database  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            ref = database.getReference();
            String userID = ref.push().getKey();
            ref.push().setValue(userID);
            generateComment(view);
            ref.child(userID).setValue(addCommenttoFirebase);
        }
    });

}

public void buttonViewAllComments(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewComments.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

public void buttonSaveComment(View view) {
addCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String pushID = ref.push().getKey();

        CommentObject obj = new CommentObject(pushID, addCommenttoFirebase)

        ref.child(pushID).setValue(obj);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I tried setting the value to a comment object instead of a string and it still didn't work

Comment: Make sure your variable name within your comment obj and child node name on the database are same.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public void buttonSaveComment(View view) {
addCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        database  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref = database.getReference();

        String userID = ref.push().getKey();

        ref.child(userID).setValue(yourValue).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                              //Success
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                               //Failed
                           }
                       });          
        generateComment(view);
    }
});
```